# How to store database in a server for access on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, database, json

I'm designing an iOS app which will need 'User' functionality. I want to store these users on a `database` on a domain I bought on GoDaddy.com. So, how should I go about making the database ?

Second, I want to access these users via JSON, maybe ? Or XML ? I'm an iOS developer and don't have much idea about the performance optimisations required for web development, so which will the preferred way ?

Also, how do I add a user ? This is a purely theoretical question. Do I send a JSON object ? Do I send a `String` ? And what do I need to do on the server-side to facilitate this functionality ?

Format your answers in simple steps, if possible. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a web api for storing and reterving data to and from the server. You will have to create `database` on server (you can do this by using web interface for MySql databse available in go dady), after that create web api in php or whatever, whcih will be an iterface to store and retrieve data.

Better to use `JSON` as it is lightweight and easy to parse, `XML` is heavy weight and also need more effort to parse.

Yes you have to send `JSON` to the web api and your web api should save user to databse and will send you some `JSON` based response, which you can use to show some message in api (successful or failure). 
[Here](http://www.jsonrpc.org/specification) you can find how you structure your JSON request and response object.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need:

1. A web space (you have it)
2. A database, mySQL is free and almost supported from every web-space provider on earth
3. A web-server proxy that let you interact with the database from an http request. The easiest way to do so is with PHP which have json extension and is very simple to setup.
4. iOS side, a json client (quite easy to implement).

Comment: Thanks, but I've accepted C_X's answer. Yours still helps a lot. Thank You.